# Is there anything travelling at near $c$? Perhaps $(1/2)c$ or $(3/4)c$?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, reference-frames, speed-of-light

There are lots of things traveling at c, light being the most apparent, and gravity, etc.  And there are things that travel at very high speed, like binary pulsars that might be moving at 1/4c.  But what is between these, say traveling at 1/2c or 3/4c or more?

Comment: I don't suppose that light traveling through glass or diamond counts... How about stuff falling into black holes?

Comment: @PM2Ring  does something falling into a black hole reach those speeds?  Do you have a reference?

Comment: Aren't *you* traveling near $c$ with respect to some reference frames?

Comment: Well, it depends on the coordinates you're using. To a distant Schwarzschild observer, nothing crosses the EH. But to an observer hovering near the EH, infalling matter approaches *c*. (Achieving the required acceleration without getting crushed is admittedly tricky). Of course, that's assuming that there isn't an accretion disk in the way.

Comment: @PM2Ring  This article says a planet reached 1/3c, which is still bloody fast  https://www.space.com/41923-black-hole-material-one-third-light-speed.html   But I'm really thinking of true relativistic speeds, where time dilation and energy requirements would reach huge levels.

Comment: Small isolated things falling into a BH approach *c*, since that's the escape velocity at the EH, but large amounts of stuff tends to create a "traffic jam", aka an accretion disk. Like bathwater going down the plughole, it can't just instantly fall in at  once, and it generally has a lot of angular momentum it needs to shed.

Comment: I am currently traveling at exactly .7c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well cosmic rays travel at between 43 and 99.6% of the speed of light, for example:

http://www.srl.caltech.edu/personnel/dick/cos_encyc.html

Comment: And what to think about the protons in the LHC at CERN? They are accelerated up to 99,9% of the speed of light. So the answer is certainly YES!

Comment: Also, stellar neutrinos. (The neutrinos in the cosmic neutrino background are probably a bit too slow).

Comment: For those wondering why there's a somewhat specific reason for 43%, is because that's about the kinetic energy of a 100 MeV proton. I'm used to GeV energies for protons, but I guess one could say down to MeV ranges as well.

Comment: This misses the main point, which is that velocity is relative.

Comment: They can also travel at above 99.6% c, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh-My-God_particle

Answer (score 1):

Any material object can be traveling at any speed $v<c$, if you just pick the right frame of reference.